# Angular: embedding a directive's template in one of its parameters's markup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to provide an optional parameter for a directive, which can be used to surround the directive's template. This is a basic example of what I have:

```
angular
    .module('test')
        .directive('dropdownField', dropDownFn);

    function dropDownDirective Fn(termParameters, restService) {
        return {
            scope: { 
                'markup' : "=?"
            },
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: "vm",

            templateUrl: "dropdown.tpl.html",
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) { ... }
        }
    }
```

HTML could look like this:

```
    <dropdown-field
        markup="<div class='thisIsTheSurroundingMarkup'></div>"
    ></dropdown-field>
```

or this:

```
    Inside the controller:
    $scope.thisIsTheSurroundingMarkupFromTheController = "<div class='thisIsTheSurroundingMarkup'></div>";

    <dropdown-field>
      {{ thisIsTheSurroundingMarkupFromTheController }}
    </dropdown-field>
```

Both would/should generate the following outcome:

```
    <div class='thisIsTheSurroundingMarkup'>
        <select ...>...</select> <-- this comes from dropdown.tpl.html 
    </div>
```

I guess this is one with ngTransclude, however, I am not sure how. Could anybody point me into the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Could fix this by myself.

```
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
            tElement.wrap(tAttrs.markup);
        },
```